# UNEXPLAINABLE DHCP Leasing using LEDE/OpenWRT (LuCI)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp, openwrt

So this all started when trying run an `apt-get update` on my Raspberry Pi0. My setup is as follows:

I have a Netgear WNR2000v5 router set up with a relay bridge between the LAN ports and the client interface connected to my main WiFi. The RPi0 is connected to the Netgear router via MiniUSB > USB Hub w/ ethernet adapter.

The client interface (`wwan`) is set up with a static ip as shown:

Client static IP config:

[image]

The LAN network is set up with the configuration below in accordance with an OpenWRT tutorial for relay bridge.

LAN static ip config:

[image]

The relay bridge joins the two interfaces:

Relay bridge config:

[image]

A DHCP server is only configured for the LAN interface. The netgear router currently has 4 devices connected via the ports:

- Samsung TV
- Raspberry Pi B+
- Desktop PC
- Raspberry Pi 0

## Weird things to mention:

My ISP is XFinity so I am able to use XFi to monitor the IP addresses connected on the network.

1) The Samsung TV says that it is connected to the internet with ip address `10.0.0.128`. XFi says that a Samsung TV is connected with IP address `10.0.0.228`

2) The Raspberry Pi B+ is visible in the LEDE DHCPv6 Leases with IP address `10.0.0.84`. I can `ssh` (sometimes - otherwise I get a connection timeout) into the Pi from my main network (i.e. without being connected via the LAN ports on the netgear router). An `apt-get update` works through ssh for the RPi B+.

3) With the Wifi disabled on my PC, I can access the internet perfectly. The PC says its IP address `10.0.0.200`. It doesn't even show up on XFi or in LuCI. Also, I can VNC to the PC with its stated address.

4) This is what is most mind-boggling to me... The Raspberry Pi 0 is receiving a DHCP lease for a different network range. The only difference in this connection is the USB adapter. Would that even matter? A picture of what is seen in LuCI is below:

LuCI device leases:

[image]

I have tried changing the RPi0 to have a static IP in the network range I want (`10.0.0.0`) but I must not be doing it right.

There is bunch more information I have gone through but before I clutter the post, I would like to see if there is something obvious that I am missing. However, there is way to much weird stuff going on for me to even know where to start... What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so since I am a networking noob I'm not sure why this worked but I added a static route and it seemed to solve my problem:

[image]

Not sure what the route type should be but unicast works I guess

Still not sure about all the other weirdness - would still appreciate an explanation.

Update: I have no idea why specifying the lan interface worked the first time but stopped working shortly after. By specifying the `relay_bridge` interface things seem to work consistently.

UPDATE: 
I am leaving the above answer in case it had any merit (though I think the configuration was coincidently jumbled in a way that things miraculously worked for a bit). Since the configuration ended up terminating, I’m not sure that the answer above is at all correct. Instead, what I have now that has been consistently working is this:

After following this tutorial exactly: https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wifi/relay_configuration
I played with the ipv4 netmasks for both the lan and wwan interfaces until devices were visible* to the network and devices connected via lan had internet access. In addition, I enabled network masquerading under Network > Firewall. For lan, the ipv4 netmask was 255.0.0.0 and for wwan the ipv4 netmask was 255.255.255.0. If the tutorial did not give information to fill out a field, the field was left blank.

- by “visible” I mean I could access the devices on the network by their known IP. Oddly enough, a network scan is not able to detect those devices (this is another question on Super User)